# React-Native: How to determine if MapView is currently tracking user location?

Tags: ios, maps, react-native

I'm building a ReactNative iOS app that uses MapView. (Actually, right now I'm testing [`react-native-maps`](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps), but I think they're at least largely similar.)

I want to implement a "center map around me" feature akin to the one in Apple's Maps.app.

In the first of these two screen shots (sorry for the size), the blue button is highlighted and the map is correctly positioned around my current location:

[image: Centered on me]

In the second screen shot, I've panned the map a bit so that it's no longer centered on my current location and the button is no longer highlighted.

[image: I panned the map]

If I tap the button, the map snaps back to my current location again.

How can I implement this button in my own app?

I don't see any way to access the state of the map (i.e. is it tracking user's location or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, saying that

> (Actually, right now I'm testing react-native-maps, but I think they're at least largely similar.)

is not true as they are using different native files to handle the bridge between React and iOS/Android.

Concerning react-native-maps, you can animate map center coordinates by using `animateToCoordinate` method which is documented [here](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md). To do so, you should give a ref to your MapView (and maybe even use `MapView.Animated` class).

Basically, you can declare your map like this

```
<MapView.Animated
  ref="map"
  showsUserLocation={true}
/>
```

And then create a method:

```
centerOnUser(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.refs.map.refs.node.animateToCoordinate(position.coords)
    },
    (error) => alert(error.message),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
  );
}
```

And call this method from your button.

Comment: OK, that answers a part of my question, but not all of it. I was hoping also for advice on how to know when the map gets panned away from the current user's location.

Comment: This can be done with onRegionChange/onRegionChangeComplete functions prop of Mapview. You will have the current region (lat lng and lat, lng delta's) as argument and you could compare it with user location. If your user location is not inside the region you could call conterOnUser. Does this help?

Comment: OK, this "works," but not as smoothly as the Apple Maps app. Accepting, but still hoping for a better answer.

Comment: @user2015762, Hi, When I try this piece of code I get the following error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.refs.map.refs.node.animateToCoordinate')". Any suggestions?

Comment: You are right, API has changed, you should now use 
`<MapView.Animated ref={ref => { this.map = ref; }} showsUserLocation={true} />`
and then
`this.map.animateToCoordinate(position.coords);`

Tell me if it works and I'll update the answer